# Spring boot 2 (spring batch app) fails to start. Fails with BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Console'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, h2

I am trying to run a Spring Batch app that reads data from a SQL Server DB and writes to a csv file. Below is the DatabaseConfiguration file for the SQL Server DB:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.sample.repository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "sampleEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transManager"
)
public class CompensationConfiguration
{
    @Primary
    @Bean(name="cmpnDS")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sample.datasource.compensation")
    public DataSource sampleDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "sampleEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sampleEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                           @Qualifier("cmpnDS") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.opencodez.entity")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager hrprdTransactionManager(@Qualifier("sampleEntityManagerFactory")
                                                                      EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryBean) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryBean);
    }
}
```

Following is a snippet from the pom file:-

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>mybat</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>mybat</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.6</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the following in the properties file:-

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

When I try to launch the app it is failing to start with the below error:-

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
```

This app reads a SQL Server DB for processing records. The spring batch uses in memory DB H2Database. Is this a multi-datasource scenario? I didn't do any coding for the datasource configuration of H2 as it should be autoconfigured. I have all the required dependencies included in the pom - sprign-batch-core, devtools, h2 database, jpa etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two Datasource Configuration classes, one for each database, and marked the h2 datasource as primary. The app started fine after this change.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by setting

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=false
```

in my spring boot application.properties file.

[The doc for that property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-sql-h2-console) says that you could get rid of this by instead removing the pom dependency for spring-boot-devtools ([detailed here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete h2's related jar files in .m2 maven local repository, It's must be corrupted.

After that, you have to run "mvn spring-boot:run" again, Maybe more that one jar was corrupted so check it and reapet recipe (every time you need to run that command after delete that jar).